# Having drama with Z-Index

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, nav

I know there are a lot of questions on here about using z-index and the majority of them have been just applying the wrong positioning. For the life of me I cannot get this to work despite going through Q&As, forums and tutorials. This is my setup:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
<div class="headerTop">
    <div class="headerTopLeft">
        <div class="headMid">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headerTopRight">
        <div class="headMid">
        <b>Name</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="headerBottom">
    <div class="headerBottomLeft">
        <div class="headMid">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headerBottomRight">
        <div class="headMid">
        <div id="home"><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png"></a></div>
        <div id="friends"><a href="#"><img src="images/friends.png"></a></div>
        <div id="mail"><a href="#"><img src="images/mail.png"></a></div>
        <div id="photos"><a href="#"><img src="images/photos.png"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header {
position: relative;
height: 105px;
background: repeat-x url('../images/header_bg.jpg');
width: 100%;
color: #FFF;
display: table;
}
.headerTop {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: 70px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
.headerTop > .headerTopLeft {
position: relative;
float: left;
height: 70px;
width: 400px;
display: table;
}
.headerTopRight {
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 70px;
width: 480px;
display: table;
text-align: right;
}
.headerBottom {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 960px;
height: 35px;
padding: 0 20px;
}
.headerBottom > .headerBottomLeft {
float: left;
height: 35px;
width: 400px;
display: table;
}
.headerBottom > .headerBottomRight {
float: right;
height: 35px;
width: 480px;
display: table;
text-align: right;
}
.headMid {
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 480px;
float: right;
}
#home {
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 24px;
z-index: 100;
}
#friends {
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 24px;
z-index: 100;
}
#mail {
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 24px;
z-index: 100;
}
#photos {
position: relative;
width: 30px;
height: 24px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Sorry for the long includes but I thought it was best to show you it all.

The issue is that the divs within `headerBottomRight` are showing on seperate lines on the left of the containing div. I need these 4 divs (`home` `friends` `mail` and `photos`) to be positioned in the right-hand-side of the `headerBottomRight` div. The reason for z-index is because I want to put small badges over the top at some point. First things first though, please help!

**EDIT: ** http://jsfiddle.net/zBZ3j/

Comment: I tried to put the above in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUxJr/) but without the images I can't tell what's going on.

Comment: fixed up a rough fiddle

Comment: @matt1985, the four divs are on seperate lines because they are block level elements, you either need to float them or make them inline-block elements.  I don't get where z-index comes into this

Comment: @pete thanks for the inline-block idea! worked perfectly with the answer marked as correct :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these to your child div, which you wanna have in the right :

```
display:block;
min-width: 30px;
width:100%;
float: right;
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SS847/)

one example

```
#photos {
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    z-index: 100;
    display:block; /*added*/
    min-width: 30px; /*added*/
    width:100%; /*added*/
    float: right; /*added*/
}
```

**why it was not working :** because you didn't provide the layout for child's of `headMid` class, so they tend to take the left place!! :)

**EDIT**

To align in same line, remove `width:100%`  [**see demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SS847/1/)

Comment: This indeed floats them to the right but they still show on seperate lines. I want them all to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WEz5h/) is a working example. In this way you can exclude `z-index` in place of `position: relative` to position other elements in the bottom.